# What port is this and what is is used for?

Tags: hard-drive

I have long wondered what this port is on some harddrives?

I assume it may be some sort of serial or factory programming port. The top-most hard drive in the stack pictured below is an SSD, it has the same pins, just not broken out on a connector.

[image: mystery port]

Comment: These are jumpers that are used for various things depending on the HDD manufacture. In a land no so long ago, some IDE HDDs used these jumpers for master/slave designation. [This question was answered here as well](http://superuser.com/questions/56270/why-does-a-sata-hard-drive-have-jumpers/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are jumper pin arrays for sata specific options. IDE drives could be daisy chained so they had more options so they used 8-pin arrays, but its the same basic concept. jumper a pair of pins to enable a setting.

see more info here:
[What is the purpose of this 4-pin interface on SATA HDDs and why doesn't it exist on SSDs?](https://superuser.com/questions/441817/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-4-pin-interface-on-sata-hdds-and-why-doesnt-it-exis)