# force OCZ TRION 100 SSD to SATA-I mode

Tags: ssd

I have an old **ASUS K8V Deluxe** motherboard with **VIA VT8237 SB**:
[image: VIA VT8237 SB]
..which [doesn't support 3Gbps SATA-II](http://support.asus.com.cn/faq/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&m=K8V%20Deluxe&s=20&hashedid=7fNMh0ZOSKQjjNym&os=&no=967AE01F-E477-0A29-4EC2-A6455EE3B94E). I had two older SSDs at home- [OCZ TRION 100(TRN100-25SAT3-120G)](http://ocz.com/consumer/trion-100-ssd/specifications) and  [Corsair Force LS 60GB(CSSD-F60GBLSB)](http://www.corsair.com/en/force-series-ls-60gb-sata-3-6gb-s-ssd-b). While latter is detected by motherboard:
[image]

..then OCZ TRION 100 is not. It obviously doesn't have a jumper to force SSD to SATA-I mode.

Is there a way to force OCZ TRION 100 SSD to 1Gbps SATA-I mode? Maybe it is possible to force this in SSD firmware?

Comment: Dropbox image isn't accessible.  Upload it to `i.stack.imgur.com`.  I have never heard of a jumper existing on **any** SATA device to enable/disable SATA-I mode.  SATA-II and SATA-III devices are backwards compatible with SATA-I, the reason your drive isn't detectable, is for another reason.

Comment: **ALL** SATA-3 devices are compatible with SATA-II and SATA-I, the performance might be abysmal, but its a SATA specification requirement.  Given that the OCZ is "Fully compliant with Serial ATA International Organization: Serial ATA Revision 3.1." means there is no technical reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: I uploaded Dropbox images to Imgur. Thanks for pointing this out! However, there definitely has been SATA devices which have a jumper to force those devices to 1.5Gbps operations(I guess it is the same as SATA-I) mode. For example [ST3500320AS](http://i.imgur.com/Kippaws.jpg).

Comment: [You are indeed correct](http://superuser.com/questions/56270/why-does-a-sata-hard-drive-have-jumpers) but all that does is limit the transfer rates. I still maintain, the device should work, with or without the jump.  If the device does not have the jumper, to limit the transfer rates, then there isn't a way to limit the transfer rates

Comment: Weren't early VIA SATA chipsets kind of dodgy at best? Seems to me, even back when they were new, there were some compatibility issues.

Comment: Looks like indeed this particular VIA SATA chipset accepts only devices which are strictly SATA-I only. @Ramhound I was hoping that there is a way to for example flash the SSD firmware in a way which simulates the behavior of "1.5Gbps operations" jumper on older SATA HDDs.

Comment: You can't change what the chipset does or does not support with firmware.

Comment: If older SATA HDDs support this with a jumper, then at least theoretically it is possible in case of modern SSDs as well.

Comment: @Martin Have you considered emailing or calling OCZ Technical Support? http://ocz.com/consumer/support

Comment: @acejavelin Yes I did. According to them it is an incompatibility with the chipset. However, I'm pretty sure that if I could force this SSD to SATA-I mode only, then it would work with the motherboard because that's exactly how it behaves with HDDs. I have two other HDDs besides ST3500320AS which have this "SATA-I mode" jumper and they are detected only in case this "SATA-I mode" is enabled. I was simply hoping maybe SSDs have some sort of non-volatile memory which can be written with specialized utility and thus tweak some settings like SATA operation mode. Something similar to CMOS for BIOS.

Comment: @Martin I meant did you ask OCZ support about how to force it into SATA-I only mode? They would likely be the ones who know best... Worst case scenario, how about hooking it up to a PCI SATA RAID card or other SATA card that has onboard BIOS that's bootable?